# How to pass props to child React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

How can i pass props to React Child Component ?
I got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of null

child
D:/T97/React-Test/test/src/child.js:6
  3 | const child = (props) => {
  4 |   const {user} = props;
  5 |   return (
> 6 |     <div className="child">
  7 |       {user.user_id}
  8 |     </div>
  9 |   );
View compiled
```

When i replace `user.user_id` in child.js by `JSON.stringify(user)`, i got:

```
{"user_id":1,"password":"null","user_name":"User1","email":"user@gmail.com","avatar_url":"https://picsum.photos/300/300"}
```

API: ("http://localhost:5000/user/1")

```
{"user_id":1,"password":"null","user_name":"User1","email":"user@gmail.com","avatar_url":"https://picsum.photos/300/300"}
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Child from './child';
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5000/user/1',
      );
      setUser(result.data);
    };
 
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child user={user}/>
    </div>
  );
}
 
export default App;
```

child.js

```
import React from 'react';

const child = (props) => {
  const {user} = props;
  return (
    <div className="child">
      {user.user_id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default child;
```

Comment: I believe `const {user} = props;` is not compiled well and user actually empty. if you could share debugging it will be great. try using props directly instead of user.

Comment: `const [user, setUser] = useState(null);` -- `user` begins as null. This is causing the error. Later on it *becomes* an object with properties you can access, but until the axios request completes and triggers a re-render, it is not an object.

Comment: It is because on first render, `user` is null because of `const [user, setUser] = useState(null);`, therefore in the child component you have to put `if (user ==null) return null`. Then it wont give you an error and when user is not null anymore it will render well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first rendering the user is not yet available (it's null initially), after the axios request/response is done the user will be available and you could use in your components, but you have to add a conditional rendering when the user is null :

```
   <div className="child">
      {user && user.user_id}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The child component will complete it's first render before you get the response from your API call. In that case, your child component will receive 'user' object as null as it's the initial state is null because of this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
```

You can either set your initial set to an empty object like this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
```

Or you can add one more condition in your child component

```
<div className="child">
    {user && user.user_id}
</div>
```

Once you get the response from API, the user state will be updated and you'll get your desired output.

Here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eutbvw?file=src%2FApp.js